# How to check user roles in View MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

As the question says, I am trying to check for a user object's roles in MVC5 View. Basically what my view does is a listing of all the registered users and their current role.

Here's my view:

```
    @model IEnumerable<IconicMx.CandidateDatabase.Models.ApplicationUser>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Talent Center Institute: Usuarios";
    ViewBag.Menu = "Usuarios";
    ViewBag.Submenu = "Lista de usuarios";
    ViewBag.MenuFaClass = "fa-cog";
    ViewBag.InitialPanel = true;
}

<h2>Lista de usuarios</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Crear usuario", "Register", "Account", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </th>
        <th>
            Tipo de usuario
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
        </td>
        <td>
            @if (ViewBag.manager.IsInRole(item.Id, "Admin"))
            {
                <text>Administrador</text>
            }
            else
            {
                <text>Capturista</text>
            }
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Editar", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-xs" }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Eliminar", "Delete", new { id=item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-xs" })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

And here's my controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>());
        return View(db.Users.ToList());
    }
```

I am trying to use the UserManager's IsInRole function but a runtime error appears when rendering the view saying that function is not defined!! If I invoke this function in the controller it runs as expected.

NOTE: I am NOT trying to get the current logged in User in the session!! (User.identity.IsInRole doesn't help)

Comment: I think it would probably be best to put this information into a view model and pass the information to the view that way, instead of trying to access the `IUserManager` instance in the view itself. Separate the concerns: prepare the data for the view in the controller, and display the data with the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, get your data out of database in controller and pass data into your view, not references to service classes. This will save you a lot of headaches. ViewBag is good for passing an odd **serialiseable** object, but not so good in passing references to classes that have a lot of behaviour.

Second, you need to use `IsInRoleAsync` [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt151686(v=vs.108).aspx#M:Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager%602.IsInRoleAsync(%601,System.String)) on UserManager. Yes, there is `IsInRole` non-async extension method available, but I don't see you having a required namespace used.

So I'd do a view model class: 
    public class UserViewModel
    {
        public String Id { get; set; }
        public String Username { get; set; }
        public String Email { get; set; }
        public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
        // other properties
    }

Then adjust your controller to do the data extraction:

```
private UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;

public MyController()
{
    userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>());
}

public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    var viewModels = db.Users.Select(u => new UserViewModel(){ Id = u.Id, Username = u.Username, Email = u.Email }).ToList();
    foreach (var userModel in viewModels)
    {
        userModel.IsAdmin = await userManager.IsInRoleAsync(userModel.Id, "Admin");
    }

    return View(viewModels);
}
```

Then adjust your view to take a `List<UserViewModel>` and present the data accordingly - I'll leave that to you to finish.

Comment: OK.. I tried to avoid making a intermediate class but I now realize while trying to do that I am not even doing MVC anymore as I am combining View & controller stuff. Thank you!